# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'thinc.neural'

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, spacy

I'm having trouble running my code, here are the results of the error I got :

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-35-d0706627a935> in <module>
      1 # import the function to train using spaCy
----> 2 from train_spacy import train_spacy

~\TA\train_spacy.py in <module>
      3 from spacy.util import minibatch, compounding
      4 from spacy.util import decaying
----> 5 from thinc.neural.optimizers import Adam
      6 import random
      7 from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'thinc.neural'
```

The following are the related modules installed on my OS.

C:\Users\Anonymous>pip list | findstr spacy 
 spacy                              3.0.5 
 spacy-legacy                       3.0.1 
 C:\Users\Anonymous>pip list | findstr thinc 
 thinc                              8.0.2

If there are other statements that I have not explained, please ask me, and I ask for your help because I have tried to reinstall the module but are still facing the same error, and I apologize if my language is wrong. Thank you ^ - ^

Comment: I might be wrong, but it seems as if `thinc.neural` doesn't exist anymore in `thinc` since version 8.0.

Comment: Whatever script you're running was likely written for spacy v2 / thinc v7, so you'll need to downgrade spacy.

Answer (score 0):

Since a few versions ago thinc was reorganized. Classes and functions should now be imported from `thinc.api`.

As you can see, Adam is referenced in https://github.com/explosion/thinc/blob/master/thinc/api.py.